# Gitlab CI : Skipping cache archiving due to empty cache key

Tags: asp.net-core, continuous-integration, gitlab, node-modules, gitlab-ci

I can't caching node_modules for .NET core and angular project in gitlab ci script.

I have this message  `Skipping cache archiving due to empty cache key`

here is my CI JOB

```
build_job:
  stage: build
  except:
    refs:
      - tags
  tags:
    - windows
  script:
    - dotnet restore .\$CI_PROJECT_NAME.sln
    - dotnet build /p:Version=${env:VERSION} -c Release --no-restore /nr:false
  artifacts:
    name: "build-$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
    paths:
      - '$CI_PROJECT_NAME/'
      - '$CI_PROJECT_NAME.Tests/'
  cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}-node
    paths:
      - './$CI_PROJECT_NAME/ClientApp/node_modules/'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was having the same problem for my Windows runner with a C++ build. No matter what I set in my `.config-ci.yml` file I could not get my third party library builds cached.

In turns out the problem was that I did not have a `cache_dir` in the `config.toml` for my Gitlab runner settings. Once I set this, the simple cache settings in my `.config-ci.yml` file worked as desired.

Unfortunately the error is misleading as to which key in which configuration file is missing.

Comment: I also had this problem with windows and your solution fixed my problem. Agreed that the error message is very wrong.

Comment: On windows, you need to have the cache_dir on the same drive as the builds_dir. This is because internally, GitLab tries to construct a relative path from the builds_dir to the cache_dir, even if you specify a full qualified path in cache_dir.